# Problem with Zomato API endpoint dailymenu

Tags: api, zomato-api

I´ve been trying to use the endpoint dailymenu from Zomato Api but I always get this response

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "status": "Bad Request",
  "message": "No Daily Menu Available"
}
```

Here it is a printscreen of the call

[image: Api call]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Daily menu is available for Prague, Czech Republic only not any other city or country around the world.

Answer (score 0):

It states that the restaurant `res_id` is invalid (for whatever reason; the ID might even exist, but not may publish their daily menus). The [documentation](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/restaurant) does not mention any geographic limitation. For a test, this would be one `res_id` in New York City: `16774318` (taken from the docs).